# Ethernet works with Windows Vista Ultimate, but not in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

When I installed ubuntu 14.04 my ethernet is not connecting. Anyone can help me , please ?

```
NetworkManager Tool
State: disconnected
Device: eth0
Type: Wired
Driver: r8169
State: unavailable
Default: no
HW Address: 00:24:1D:13:3D:08
Capabilities:
Carrier Detect: yes
Wired Properties Carrier: off
```